# Database relation for dynamic foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, relation

[image]table lead: id, name, status

table lead_contact: id, lead_id(foreign key), full_name,contact

table test_drive: id lead_id(foreign key), lead_contact_id(foreign_key),vehicle_name

When i insert data in leads and lead_contact, `lead_contact` rows can be dynamic.
For eg. During insert, added 2 contacts in `lead_contact` table then after some time when updated 1 contact and removed one. For this, i am deleting all rows where `lead_id` given `lead_id` in `lead_contact` and then inserting new rows.

But this `lead_contact_id` is also present in `test_drive` table. How that rows can be cascade or sync with new id inserted for that contacts.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try to make the lead_contact_id key on cascade ?

Comment: no. cause i have to delete the rows of lead_contact first so ON DELETE CASCADE test_drive rows will also delete which has id of lead_contact_id

Comment: Please describe relation of tables (one-to-one etc.)

Comment: One(Lead)-to-Many(lead_contact) and one(test_drive)-to-one(lead_contact)

Comment: For example you got lead with id `l1` lead contact of that lead with id `lc1` and test drive of that lead and contact with id `td1`, then you add new contact with id `lc2` and delete `lc1`, and want to contact id of `td1` changed from `lc1` to `lc2`?

Comment: Added image please check. yes `l1` lead can have `lc1` and `lc2` (Relation one to many) then if i have to update details then for that i have to first delete `lc1` and `lc2` and insert the new contacts cause its dynamic depend on user if it lead some contact or add new contact for a lead.